# Expected Value of volume of any convex body excluding some points?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Consider the bounded region given by $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let it be given that we have uniformly sampled $k$ i.i.d. points ${P_i} \sim U(A)$ where $k$ is some constant.

Now $S \subseteq A$ be any convex region in $A$ s.t. forall $i$, $P_i \not\in S$. Then can we give an upper bound on the expected value of $vol(S)$ in terms of $vol(A)$, $k$, and $n$ ?

If this is not possible, what additional conditions may we assume/change on the region A and the points, so that we can come up with an upper bound for $vol(S)$?

Comment: A finite set of points has volume zero.

Comment: But based on how the points are distributed, it would put some constraint on the volume of a convex set, no?

Comment: I see what you mean. Without any information on $A$ the problem doesn't look feasible to me.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yeah I guess so. I'll let the question up just in case anyone has any ideas.